# "heroku labs:enable user-env-compile" not finding file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web

I am having an issue with my ruby web app that I am trying to deploy to Heroku. Whenever I use this command:

```
git push heroku master
```

I am getting an error message that says:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I found a solution, and that is to use this command:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

However, whenever I use that command, I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in 'require' :
no such file to load -- netric (LoadError)
```

Why isn't the `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` command finding the file?

EDIT: I am running this command in the webapp's root directory.

Comment: Do you have Heroku toolbelt installed? https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

Comment: I do have it installed.

Comment: Does your app run locally?  I'm going to be it doesn't.  When you run it locally, how do you start it?  Do you use: `bundle exec ....`  If not, you should - that's how Heroku runs it.  I suspect it's a gem / bundle problem that you have locally, that you also have on Heroku.